# Case Statement of time field

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2016

Using this case statement, and could use some help with the first condition:

```
 case
    when convert(varchar, tblrelease.releaseddt, 108) BETWEEN '22:00:00' AND '06:00:00' then '10PM to 6AM' -- 1st
    when convert(varchar, tblrelease.releaseddt, 108) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '14:00:00' then '6AM to 2PM' -- 2nd
    when convert(varchar, tblrelease.releaseddt, 108) BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '22:00:00' then '2PM to 10PM' -- 3rd 

        else 'UNDEFINED'
end AS [Shift],
```

The first case condition doesn't return '10PM to 6AM'. It should return the value as stated. Please see the sample table results:

[image]

tblrelease.releaseddt = (smalldatetime, null)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, explain what the logic should be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the syntax, I'm going to assume that the you are using SQL Server.  The simplest way to handle this code is probably to focus on the hours:

```
(case when datepart(hour, tblrelease.releaseddt) between 6 and 13
      then '6AM to 2PM'
      when datepart(hour, tblrelease.releaseddt) between 14 and 20
      then '2PM to 10PM'
      when tblrelease.releaseddt is not null          
      then '10PM to 6AM'
      else 'UNDEFINED'
 end) as Shift,
```

You can also use `time`:

```
(case when convert(time, tblrelease.releaseddt) >= '06:00:00' and
           convert(time, tblrelease.releaseddt) < '14:00:00' 
       then '6AM to 2PM' -- 2nd
       when convert(time, tblrelease.releaseddt) >= '14:00:00' and
            convert(time, tblrelease.releaseddt) < '22:00:00' 
      when tblrelease.releaseddt is not null          
      then '10PM to 6AM'
      else 'UNDEFINED'
 end) as Shift,
```

This gets around the midnight issue by looking at the other two shifts first.  Note that there is no reason to convert to a string to accomplish this.  And `BETWEEN` is not recommended.  Your code is ambiguous on where the boundaries should go.

Comment: Small clarification on that last part: `BETWEEN` includes both extremes, so if for example the time is exactly 2PM you have two "right" options, and the output will depend on the order of your conditions. @jr7138, you need to exclude one of the extremes, like Gordon did here.

Comment: BTW, @Gordon, in your first code the `'2PM to 10PM'` condition is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. Yes, Andrew, I saw the condition and fixed it on my end. This works as it should. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the query before and after midnight

```
 case
    when (convert(varchar, tblrelease.releaseddt, 108) BETWEEN '22:00:00' AND '23:59:59') OR 
         (convert(varchar, tblrelease.releaseddt, 108) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '06:00:00') then '10PM to 6AM' -- 1st
    when convert(varchar, tblrelease.releaseddt, 108) BETWEEN '06:00:00' AND '14:00:00' then '6AM to 2PM' -- 2nd
    when convert(varchar, tblrelease.releaseddt, 108) BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '22:00:00' then '2PM to 10PM' -- 3rd 

        else 'UNDEFINED'
end AS [Shift],
```